# javascript in Angular 4

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

I am using angular 4 in visual studio code. I want to include a javascript function in my code .

home.component.html

```
 <html>
 <body>

 <button onclick="myFunction()">Click me</button>

 <p id="demo"></p>

 <script>
function myFunction() {
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Hello World";
}
  </script>

</body>
</html>
```

But when i clicking on the button, then its showing error : "Uncaught ReferenceError: myFunction is not defined at HTMLButtonElement.onclick"

Comment: Why do declare a function in HTML instead of component?

Comment: you don't need html tag inside your component and angular has a way to implement events. Check this:https://angular.io/guide/user-input

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You dont need to write javascript code in HTML file in angular.

There is seprate typescript file withextension .ts where you can put your javascript code in typescript style.

Use below structure for above code in angular :

**home.component.html**

```
 <button (click)="myFunction()">Click me</button>
 <p>{{demo}}</p>
```

**home.component.ts**

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home.component.css'],
  providers: []
})
export class AppComponent {
 public demo: string;

myFunction(){
this.demo="Hello World";
}
}
```

Code online :https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gwrvbn?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Answer (score 1):

You can also use script file into your angular project.

1. create js file and put your script code into it, and put that js file into `assets` folder.
2. Now goto root directory of your angular app, there you can find a file name `.angular-cli.json`

Now edit that file, find **`"scripts"`** and write **`"script": ["assets/your_script_file.js"]`**.

Now you can call the functions written in that script in your html file.